# How to pass jQuery Variable to Laravel Helper Parameter?

Tags: jquery, laravel

I have a jquery value which looks like this:

```
user = val['name'];
```

Also, the `var user = ''` is defined above. Now, I have created a helper function and need to pass the value of the user as a parameter to my helper function.

So, I am doing this:

```
var a = {{chatDetails(user)}}
```

But, it throws an error saying use of undefined constant user. How can I pass this value?

P.S. : Everything is done in `<script></script>`

Comment: The helper will be called on the server side when the JS was not triggered yet.

Comment: So, how should I proceed?